# Changing text in an svg component created with <g> tag, and used with <use>, is that possible?

Tags: svg

I want to create a component in svg that I can reuse.
This draws a rectangle with a text in it:

```
    <g id='TestComponent'>
        <rect x='200' y='235' width='100' height='30' rx='10' style='fill: white; stroke: lightgrey;'/>
        <text x='250' y='252' text-anchor='middle' alignment-baseline='middle' style='fill:black;font-family: Helvetica'>Test</text>
    </g>
```

If I define it between the container 'g' element: 
        
            
            Test

I can then use it like this:

```
    <use xlink:href='#TestComponent' />
```

And I can also move it and reuse it with:

```
    <use xlink:href='#TestComponent' x=100 y=100 />
```

Here's my problem, I want to be able to change the text. Is that possible?
What I would like to do is something like:

```
    <use xlink:href='#TestComponent' text="Hello world 2"/>
```

Is there a way to do this?
If it's not, what is the prefered way for structuring this kind of thing so I can resuse and avoid duplication as much as possible?

/Hans

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use XSLT or javascript. Your requirements are not met by what <use> provides out-of-the-box.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can reuse parametrized structures in SVG. Look at description and examples at: [www.w3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVGParamPrimer/) or [www.schepers.cc](http://www.schepers.cc/w3c/svg/params/ref.html).